# Matplotlib save PNG graph - bitdepth

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a graph with Matplotlib that consists of up to 16 colors.

I want to save this graph as a **4 bit PNG** instead of a **16 bit PNG** (the Matplotlib default) to make the image size smaller.

- It is possible to save PNG image with Matplotlib in less than 16bit color depth?
- Is there any other method for changing the bit depth of a PNG image?

Comment: Tried anything already?

Comment: There is a [`dpi`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) parameter - you could reduce the size with that.

Comment: I changed the dpi value to lower values, but image quality becomes really bad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.